# How to setup or specify a Controllers folder for ASP.NET MVC to use instead of the default Controllers folder under?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm using VS2008 and .net 3.5.  I have created a class library(Myproject.Controllers) in my solution.  Under this class, I have added a Controllers folder.  And in the folder I have added a MyController which is  declared as 
public class MyController : Controller

My views are still in the default Views folder.  Now, when I run this in VS, I get a message in the Default.aspx.cs:
{"The controller for path '/' could not be found or it does not implement IController."}

If I put a copy of my MyController in the default Controllers folder then it works fine.  Does anyone know how I can set/configure the Controllers path?  I've searched the web and didn't find anything for this.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

By creating your own Controller factory, you can specify exactly how controllers are used.  Here's how

step 1 - create a class and derive it from `IControllerFactory`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.icontrollerfactory_members.aspx

step 2 - Consume your new Controller Factory in application start

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(typeof(MyControllerFactory));
```

`IControllerFacotry` implements 2 methods

```
IController IControllerFactory.CreateController(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName);
void IControllerFactory.ReleaseController(IController controller);
```

And that's all there is to it.

Answer (score 0):

I did this not too long ago, and the only tricky part was to make sure that the **namespace** where the controller resides is the same as it would be if it was in the default folder. The main pitfall is the root namespace of the class library project - you can change it by right-clicking the project node in Solution Explorer, selecting *Properties* and changing the value in the *Root Namespace* textbox. The easiest way is to name it the same as the MVC application itself.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, this should just work.  Did you add your Controllers library as a reference to your web site?

From MVC source

```
// ControllerTypeCache.cs:
private static List<Type> GetAllControllerTypes(IBuildManager buildManager) {
    // Go through all assemblies referenced by the application and search for
    // controllers and controller factories.

// DefaultControllerFactory.cs
// if all else fails, search every namespace
return GetControllerTypeWithinNamespaces(controllerName, null /* namespaces */);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue using dotnet 4.0 utilizing MVC 2.0 on IIS7.0. After checking all the normal stuff, having the right MVC assembly version and so on, i finally moved the code from a random location on the web server to /inetpub/www and recreated my site on the webserver. That seemed to have done the trick. Aparently, DotNet MVC likes to have the source under /inetpub/www to be able to resolve the MVC paths.